# "Seasons", or "Sacred Seasons"?

Tags: hebrew, psalms

Psalm 104:19,

> **עָשָׂ֣ה יָ֭רֵחַ לְמֹועֲדִ֑ים** ([Westminster Leningrad Codex](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm%20104%3A19&version=WLC;ESV))
>
> *He appointed the moon for the seasons* ([Interlinear translation](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/psalms/104-19.htm))

In the BDB (Brown Driver Briggs), **לְמוֹעֲדִ֑ים** (for the seasons), is a derivative of ["**מוֺעֵד**" or "*moed*"](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/417/mode/1up) which is "an appointed time".

So, in the context of this passage, are we merely talking about a lunar cycle, or is the author refering to "sacred seasons" of which "moeds" most often are refered to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NASB reads:

> *He **made** the moon for the seasons... (Psalm 104:19 NASB)*

Which is the better meaning of עָשָׂ֣ה. The moon was made for the לְמוֹעֲדִ֑ים or "moed," the appointed times.

The meaning in the Psalm must be consistent with the account of creation:

> *Then God said, “Let there be lights in the firmament of the heavens to divide the day from the night; and let them be for signs and seasons, and for days and years; (Genesis 1:14 NKJV)*

The lights (plural) were created to be the signs for seasons וּלְמ֣וֹעֲדִ֔ים (same word), days, and years. There is no mention of months or how they are to be determined. The moon is singular and is not a light; it was created to be an object that reflects light.

Some of the appointed times are determined by the month. For example, the Passover, Unleavened Bread, and First Fruits are observed in the first month; Shavuot is observed 7 weeks after First Fruits; Trumpets, Atonement, and Tabernacles are observed in the seventh month. If the moon is used to keep track of the months, then the Psalm is referring to these events.

However, there are also appointed times set by the weekly calendar:

> *And the Lord spoke to Moses, saying,  “Speak to the children of Israel, and say to them: ‘The feasts (מוֹעֲדֵ֣י) of the Lord, which you shall proclaim to be holy convocations, these are My feasts (מוֹעֲדָֽי).‘Six days shall work be done, but the seventh day is a Sabbath of solemn rest, a holy convocation. You shall do no work on it; it is the Sabbath of the Lord in all your dwellings. (Leviticus 23:1-3 NKJV)*

The Sabbath Day is called by the same name as the annual days. It too is the LORD's appointed time. The weekly Sabbaths are determined by counting days using the sun and not the moon.

Therefore the Psalm seems to be saying the moon was made for some but not all of the appointed times. The moon is necessary to keep the appointed times determined by the month but not the 52 weekly Sabbaths which are also appointed times.

The word "moed" can also mean appointed place. The moon goes through a cycle because of its changing location relative to the earth and the sun. The reason there is a new (or full) moon is the moon is the right location to reflect (or not) the light from the sun.

With the exception of the weekly Sabbaths, the appointed times are observed by men because the moon is in the appointed place. This is the meaning I see in the Psalm.

This can be extended. The Biblical concept of time is linear where God is working through a unique series of events which will culminate in a final resolution of all issues of good and evil.

The motion of the moon only appears to be cyclical. In reality the motion of the earth along its orbit around the sun makes every lunar cycle occur in a different location within the solar system. For example, each month the moon is full when the moon (and earth) is in a different location (along the earth's orbit around the sun) than the previous month. The sun also is in motion around the center of the Milky Way Galaxy, taking an estimated 225 million years to complete an orbit. If the age of the created world is reckoned according to Biblical methods, the sun has yet to complete a full orbit around the galaxy. This means no created object which moves through space has ever been in the same physical location (in space).

In other words, the moon has gone from one appointed place to the next place and has never been in the same place twice. The moon only appears to be going through a repetitive cycle. In reality it is measuring time exactly the same as God: on a linear basis where every moment is a unique place appointed by God.

Comment: Thank you for your response! You did use the Gen. 1:14 passage as a comparison, which the BDB also uses to compare the meaning of לְמוֹעֲדִ֑ים  . This seems to indicate that the moon is more than a loose piece of space rock, it is the means by which God ordained "special seasons" which He told Israel to keep for perpetuity. The upcoming "Blood Moon"  falling on the Feast Of Sukkot is therefore no mere accident, but a reminder of this reality,,,,

Comment: I added to the appointed place aspect. You are right about Sukkot - it is going to get very interesting the next few months and years.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can distinguish too much between the two; since the Jewish calendar is a lunar calendar, all "sacred seasons" are based on the lunar cycle. That being said, in the context of this psalm. it would seem to be merely speaking of how things are ordered in the sense of time keeping. The section from verses 19 through 30 seems to be related and in Young's Literal Translation chapter 104 is spaced to indicate topics or ideas within the chapter. When looking at this section as a whole for a context you can see the theme is time related. The rest of verse 19 also speaks of the sun. Both the sun and moon are used as time or season references in the verses following down to 30.

From Young's Literal Translation

> Psa 104:19  He made the moon for seasons, The sun hath known his place of entrance.
>   20  Thou settest darkness, and it is night, In it doth every beast of the forest creep.

This gives us a basic set of all time, day, night, and seasons.

> 21  The young lions are roaring for prey, And to seek from God their food.
>   22  The sun riseth, they are gathered, And in their dens they crouch.

A time statement about lions.

> 23  Man goeth forth to his work, And to his service--till evening.

A time statement about man.

> 24  How many have been Thy works, O Jehovah, All of them in wisdom Thou hast made, Full is the earth of thy possessions.
>   25  This, the sea, great and broad of sides, There are moving things--innumerable, Living creatures--small with great.
>   26  There do ships go: leviathan, That Thou hast formed to play in it.
>   27  All of them unto Thee do look, To give their food in its season.
>   28  Thou dost give to them--they gather, Thou dost open Thy hand--they are satisfied with good.

A seasonal time statement about the seas, shipping and food cycle of the sealife.

> 29  Thou hidest Thy face--they are troubled, Thou gatherest their spirit--they expire, And unto their dust they turn back.
>   30  Thou sendest out Thy Spirit, they are created, And Thou renewest the face of the ground.

This continues to be a time statement but in a less concrete way. It involves the cycle of life, death, and decay

Comment: When I say "based on" I don't mean that in the ontological sense.

Comment: Can you explain why you feel it would be "merely speaking of how things are ordered in the sense of time keeping."  You kind of just stated your conclusion without defending it.  Simply quote YLT does really explain how you arrived at your conclusion.

Comment: @ThaddeusB You're right! I've added commentary of my own to be clearer that the context speaks of time and not "sacred seasons"

Comment: Thanks, but no upvote now? :-Þ